# Jade render an array of strings as an array of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I'm passing data to render template:

```
res.render 'index', {data: ['a', 'b']}, function(err, html) {
});
```

in the template, I'd like to render the array `['a', 'b']` as an array in javascript:

```
script(type='text/javascript').
  var arr = #{data};
```

but they are rendered as `[a, b]`, an array of variables, what I want is variable names: `['a', 'b']`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First you need to `JSON.stringify` the data property object.

```
...
data: JSON.stringify(['a', 'b'])
...
```

Then in your Jade Template use `!{}`.

```
var arr = !{data}; // ["a","b"];
```